# Regarding Model's Scenario Property

Tags: php, yii

I currently faced with problem on "scenario" property of a model. The problem is, I have a radio button list with two items "text" and "number". Below this radio button list, I defined three keyword textfields. Now I'm using JQuery to hide/show those keyword textfield (When users selected "number" item in the radio button list, those keyword textfields are hidden.) What I'm trying to do now is to add server-side validation on an "answer" textfield. If users are selected "number" item in the radio button list, the answer must be numerical.

My current plan is to specify the scenario property of the model in the JQuery part as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#Task_0_answer_type_0").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(".keyword").show();
                <?php $task->scenario = ''?>
            }
        });
        $("#Task_0_answer_type_1").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(".keyword").hide();
                <?php $task->scenario = 'number'?>
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I changed the rules() in the model by adding the following statement:

```
array('answer', 'numerical', 'on'=> 'number'),
```

However, it does not work at all? Please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense: You first set `scenario` to `''` then some lines below you set it to `'number'`. This has no effect on the generated javascript at all.

Comment: I'm trying to change the value of scenario when users are choose different items in a radio button list. Maybe I did it wrong? Any kind suggestion?

Comment: You assume, that you could execute PHP code inside a javascript block. What really happens: First the PHP blocks are evaluated on the server. Their output (an empty string for the first and `number` for the second) is left in the javascript code. Then this code is sent to the client, where the javascript gets executed.

Comment: I see. Thank you, Michael. So if I want to perform a numerical validation on user input as long as the "NUMBER" item is selected from a radio button list, what am I suppose to do? Please give me some suggestion. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm trying to do now is to add server-side validation on an
>   "answer" textfield. If users are selected "number" item in the radio
>   button list, the answer must be numerical.

You mixed client script and server language absolutely wrong, you have to remove the part of php code from your above script since they didn't make any sense.

```
<select name="Task[options]">
         <option value="-1">Select One</option>
         <option value="1">Answer Type Text</option>
         <option value="2">Answer Type Number</option>
</select>
```

When you post your form, on your action, just make a switch there, before you perform the validation

```
if($_POST['Task']['options'] == '2'){
   $taskModel->setScenario('number');
}
```